# GraphQL fragments of different types in apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollostack

Edit: @helfer suggested this might be a bug. [Github issue](https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client/issues/763)

For a new application I am using Apollo to do the graphql management for me.
I have multiple types that can also contain other types.

To simplify my life as a developer I want to use fragments to avoid duplicated code.

I am trying to use fragments for different types together.

but the query results in an error, because Subject fragments cannot be used for the BusinessArea type.

Is this a bug or did I miss something?

Def:

```
const subjectInfo = createFragment(gql`
  fragment subjectInfo on Subject {
    id
    name
  }`
)

const businessAreaInfo = createFragment(gql`
  fragment businessAreaInfo on BusinessArea {
    id
    name
    subjects {
      ...subjectInfo
    }
  }`,
  [subjectInfo]
)

graphql(gql`
query {
  businessAreas {
    ...businessAreaInfo
  }
}
`, {
  fragments: businessAreaInfo
})
```

Resulting query:

```
{
  businessAreas {
    ...businessAreaInfo
    ...subjectInfo
  }
}

fragment businessAreaInfo on BusinessArea {
  id
  name
  subjects {
    ...subjectInfo
  }
}

fragment subjectInfo on Subject {
  id
  name
}
```

Comment: Is this resulting query output of `apollo`? Because resulting query should look like this: `{ businessAreas { ...businessAreaInfo } }`

Comment: That's exactly what I expected but the resulting query from my post is what is sent to the server via apollo

Comment: This looks like it could be a bug, you should file it on the apollo-client github repository.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client/issues/763

Comment: (The issue was resolved and turned out to be a bug in the app code)